# Selenium get cell based on grid coordinates

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

**I want to find a specific cell in a table based on coordinates.**

HTML

```html
<div id="model" class="mobile handsontable htRowHeaders htColumnHeaders" style="height: 100%; overflow: hidden;" data-originalstyle="height: 100%; overflow: hidden;">
  <div class="ht_master handsontable"><div class="wtHolder" style="position: relative; height: 380px; width: 1468px;">
  <div class="wtHider" style="width: 2550px; height: 2109px;">
    <div class="wtSpreader" style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
      <table class="htCore">
        <colgroup>
          <col class="rowHeader" style="width: 50px;">
          <col style="width: 400px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
          <col style="width: 70px;">
        </colgroup>
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th class="">
              <div class="relative">
                <span class="colHeader cornerHeader">&nbsp;</span>
              </div>
            </th>
            <th class=""> 
              <div class="relative">
                <span class="colHeader">Division, Base Alternative</span>
              </div>
             </th>
            <th class="">
              <div class="relative">
                <span class="colHeader">2015 (M)</span>
              </div>
             </th>
            <th class="">
              <div class="relative">
                <span class="colHeader">2016 (N)</span>
              </div>
             </th>
            <th class="">
              <div class="relative">
                <span class="colHeader">2017 (O)</span>
              </div>
             </th>
            <th class="">
              <div class="relative">
                <span class="colHeader">2018 (P)</span>
              </div>
             </th>
            <th class="">
              <div class="relative">
                <span class="colHeader">2019 (Q)</span>
              </div>
            </th>
           </tr>
          <thead>
            <tr>                                                                                                     <th class="" style="height: 17px;">
                <div class="relative">
                  <span class="rowHeader">1</span>
                </div>
                </th>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap"></td>
              <td class="afterHiddenColumn htDimmed htNoWrap"></td>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap"></td>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap"></td>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap"></td>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap"></td>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap"></td>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap"></td>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap"></td>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap"></td>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap"></td>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap"></td>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap"></td>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap"></td>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap"></td>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap"></td>
            <tr>
              <th class="" style="height: 17px;">
                <div class="relative">
                  <span class="rowHeader">2</span>
                </div>
               </th>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(194, 218, 254); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: left;"></td>
              <td class="afterHiddenColumn htDimmed htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;"></td>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;"></td>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;"></td>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;"></td>
              <td class="htDimmed htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;"></td>
            </tr>
           <tr>
            <th class="" style="height: 17px;">
              <div class="relative">
                <span class="rowHeader">3</span>
              </div>
             </th>
            <td class="htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(194, 218, 254); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: left;">Model period</td>
            <td class="afterHiddenColumn htRight htNumeric htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 128); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">0</td>
            <td class="htRight htNumeric htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 128); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">0</td>
            <td class="htRight htNumeric htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 128); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">0</td>
            <td class="htRight htNumeric htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 128); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">0</td>
            <td class="htRight htNumeric htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 128); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">0</td>
            <td class="htRight htNumeric htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 128); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">0</td>
            <td class="htRight htNumeric htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 128); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">0</td>
            <td class="htRight htNumeric htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 128); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">0</td>
          </tr>         
        <tr>
          <th class="" style="height: 17px;">
            <div class="relative">
              <span class="rowHeader">7</span>
            </div>
           </th>
          <td class="htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(194, 218, 254); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: left;">Pulp sales, pulp mill, MUSD</td>
          <td class="afterHiddenColumn htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">0</td>
          <td class="htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">0</td>
          <td class="htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">597</td>
          <td class="htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">572</td>
          <td class="htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">648</td>
          <td class="htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">35</td>
          <td class="htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">326</td>
          <td class="htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">326</td>
        </tr>
       <tr>
        <th class="" style="height: 17px;">
          <div class="relative">
            <span class="rowHeader">8</span>
          </div>
         </th>
        <td class="htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(194, 218, 254); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: left;">Pulp sales, paper mill, MUSD</td>
        <td class="afterHiddenColumn htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td class="htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td class="htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td class="htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td class="htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td class="htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td class="htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td class="htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">0</td>
        <td class="htNoWrap" title="" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); font-size: 10pt; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); text-align: center;">0</td>
       </tr>
      </thead>
```

> I have tried a bunch of different methods, but I can't understand how to do it.

> I want to find a cell, based on `line 7` & column name `2017 (O)` for example, and get
> its value

> The only example I find, is to find a cell by its index or by its value, that's not what I want to accomplish.

*Thanks in advance!*

*EDIT*
I have provided more HTML code.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to get to the span element using the 'Site 2' text, right?

if so, you can locate it by using these xpaths

```
//div[text() = 'Site 2']/parent::div/div[@class = 'flex-shrink-0']/tree-node-expander[1]/span[1]
```

or

```
//div[text() = 'Site 2']/preceding-sibling::div/tree-node-expander[1]/span[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like this:

```
el = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Site 2')]/preceding::div//span")
print(el.get_attribite("class")
```

or try parent element:

```
el = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Site 2')]/parent::div//span")
```

or preceding-sibling:

```
el = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(text(), 'Site 2')]/preceding-sibling::div//span")
```

Comment: I'm getting "flex-grow-1 d-flex text-break" class name,

Answer (score 1):

Commenting on your requirement:

> I want to find a cell, based on line 7 & column name 2017 (O) for example, and get its value

For this what you can do is grab the Column headers then get index of the column to map it in Xpath as column number based on the column name.

Now by using this column number you will be able to get the row 7 values. Something suggested in the below code:

```
columnName = '2017 (O)'
rowname = '7'
driver.get(URL)

columnHeader = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//div/span[@class="colHeader"]')
headerlist = []

# Get Element header
for element in columnHeader:
    headerlist.append(element.text)
    print(element.text)

index = headerlist.index('2017 (O)') + 1

text = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div/span[@class='rowHeader' and text()='" + rowname + "']/ancestor::th/following-sibling::td[" + str(index) + "]").text
print(text)
```

***Output*** -

[image]

**And the table structure is** -

[image]